# image size and position

Tags: html, css, image

I added an image on my navigation bar but this image position is not set. So I try to set through margin. When I add `margin-right:20px` then "events" title goes to the right side but I want to set position of image right side.

Image what I try:

[image: image 1]

Image what I want:

[image: image 2]

```css
.lefttabs{
  background-color:#1E1E1E;
  color:White;
  font-family:Calibri;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:medium;
  width: 187px; 
  height: 100%;
  z-index:1;/* Stay on top */
  padding-top: 60px; 
  /* Place content 60px from the top */
  transition: 0.5s; /* 0.5 second transition effect to slide in the sidenav */
}
.lefttabs a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size:medium;
  color:White;
  width: 133px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
.lefttabs ul{
  list-style:none;
  margin:0px 20px 0px 0px;
  border:1 px solid;
  border-color:Black;
}
.lefttabs li{
  list-style:none;
}
.lefttabs li  a {
  list-style:none;
  display:block;
  padding: 0px 0px 30px 0px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
} 
.lefttabs a:hover,.offcanvas a:focus{
  color: green;
  background-color:White;
  border-bottom-color:Red;
  color:#000!important;
  border:1px solid;
}
.imga{
  margin-right:20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="lefttabs">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href=""> <img class="imga" alt="" src="images/eve.bmp" border="0" />EVENTS</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: setting float left on both (text and image) can help you

Comment: can you add a plunk, it will be easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without going trough all your CSS, this are the basics:

```css
.lefttabs{
  background:#444;
}
.lefttabs ul{
  list-style: none;
  margin:0; padding: 0;
}
.lefttabs a{
  display: block; 
  padding: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color:#fff;
  line-height: 24px;        /* 24px are icons so use same line height */
}
.lefttabs a img{
  margin:0 8px 0 0;
  vertical-align: top;     /* needed */
}
```

```html
<div class="lefttabs">
  <ul>
    <li> 
      <a href="#"><img class="imga" alt="icon" src="//placehold.it/24x24"/>EVENTS</a>
    </li>
    <li> 
      <a href="#"><img class="imga" alt="icon" src="//placehold.it/24x24/f0f"/>STUFF</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is fiddle with very small change : https://jsfiddle.net/9ns31Lu6/1

I've just added `vertical-align: middle;` to your `.imga` class.

And here is another https://jsfiddle.net/9ns31Lu6/3/ to match with somewhat your image.

And here https://jsfiddle.net/9ns31Lu6/4/ it's for multiple menu items.